# Posting a JS array via AJAXto a PHP controller

Tags: php, jquery

UPDATE: Now when I try to use .serialize on it (after using stringify on var results), I get an

Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: {"0":1,"1":2,"2":4,"3":0,"4":0,"5":4,"6":0,"7":0,"8":0,"9":0,"10":0,"11":3,"12":‌​0,"13":0}

Any ideas?

ORIGINAL POST:

I'm posting a javascript array called "results" to a php controller, but when I var_dump the resulting post I get a array with one empty element. Alerting it within the ajax still returns the fully populated array.

This is my javascript:

```
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/TimingTest/update',
            data: $(results),
```

and this is my php:

```
public function action_update()
{
    $this->auto_render = FALSE;
    $this->template = NULL;

    if ($_POST) {

        var_dump($_POST);
        exit();
```

Comment: Can you share with us the value of `$(results)` please? Why is it a jQuery object? I'm fairly certain that you can just pass `results`.

Comment: Why would you put the array in a jquery object? results can be fine on its own

Comment: results on it's own was returning the same as the object.

This is how the array's populated above in an each function.


            var results = [];
            i = 0;
            $(".slider-snap-inc").each(function() {
                r = $(this).slider('value');
                results[i] = r;
                i++;
            });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just send the information as a JSON string:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/TimingTest/update',
    data: JSON.stringify(results),
```

On the PHP side just use `json_decode()`.

If by any chance you are getting an empty string sent to your php, change your `var results = []` declaration to `var results = {}`.